# Scroll a number of lines in a Spark textarea

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, textarea, mxml

I am writing a database program that allows searches for imported books.  On the left hand side of my screen is a Spark TextArea and on the right is a List that shows the results of the search.

When I click on the List, I load the chapter into the TextArea. Here is my problem that I simply cannot figure out.  I want the top sentence in the TextArea to be the sentence that was clicked in the List.

I know how many sentences are in my TextArea because I control the "\n".  How do I get line xx at the top of TextArea?

For instance, the user searches for "truth" and finds 20 entries for this book.  He clicks on a choice in List.  That chapter is loaded into the TextArea.  This particular chapter has 400 lines.  The line I want at the top is line 230.  The user can immediately see the context for what follows his choice.  He may scroll up to see what precedes.

I've searched and tried a host of ideas but with no success.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`TextArea#scrollToRange()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/TextArea.html#scrollToRange%28%29). You just pass in the index of the first character of the result and it will scroll to the position you want. I've used it in the past and I remember it working, though it can take some work to get it working exactly as you want.

Comment: Josh, Thanks for your reply.  I had seen scrollToRange, but I let myself be misled by the doc, which stated that it indicated the beginning and end of a selection.  Regardless how I worked with the function, the sentence was always at the bottom.  So, since I knew the sentence numbers, I added three to the sentence I wanted, and my targeted sentence is usually in the middle, which is fine.  I'm new to stackoverflow.  Is there someway that I can give you some sort of points for your quick and helpful reply?

Comment: @VLVawter Glad I could help. :) On the left hand side of my answer, there is an outline of an arrow. Clicking it will mark the answer as correct and give me reputation. You can also upvote answers, though you won't be able to until you get some reputation of your own (marking an answer as correct will help you as well)

Comment: Josh, Again, thanks. Your answer made me realized that a selection did not have to be created before scrollToRange() could be used.